# How do I resolve a local file path in ASP.NET Core 3?

Tags: c#

I am using `Visual Studio Code` version `1.42` on my `Ubuntu 18.04`. I just successfully installed `sudo dotnet add package Google.Apis.Drive.v3` via terminal but I can't find a way to install `System.Web` on my `C#` project.
After doing some research I came across this which explains that basically, I need to access a `IHostingEnvironment env object`, that ASP.NET Core will take care of.

**The problem** I'm having trouble resolving local file paths. I have is that I am not familiar with this type of approach and wanted to ask if, given the code below, someone could show me how to modify it to use a `IHostingEnvironment env object`.

The problem appears in the lines that contain :

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/GoogleDriveFiles")
```

This is the rest of the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
//using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;


namespace WebApi2.Models
{
    public class GoogleDriveFilesRepository 
    {
       //defined scope.
        public static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
        // Operations....

        //create Drive API service.
        public static DriveService GetService()
        {
             //Operations.... 

        public static List<GoogleDriveFiles> GetDriveFiles()
        {
            // Other operations....
        }

       //file Upload to the Google Drive.
        public static void FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file) // <-- Error here
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                DriveService service = GetService();

                string path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/GoogleDriveFiles"), // <-- Error here
                Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                file.SaveAs(path);

                var FileMetaData = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
                FileMetaData.Name = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                FileMetaData.MimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path); // <-- Error here

                FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;

                using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
                {
                    request = service.Files.Create(FileMetaData, stream, FileMetaData.MimeType);
                    request.Fields = "id";
                    request.Upload();
                }
            }
        }


        //Download file from Google Drive by fileId.
        public static string DownloadGoogleFile(string fileId)
        {
            DriveService service = GetService();

            string FolderPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/GoogleDriveFiles/"); // <-- Error here
            FilesResource.GetRequest request = service.Files.Get(fileId);

            string FileName = request.Execute().Name;
            string FilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FolderPath, FileName);

            MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();

            request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += (Google.Apis.Download.IDownloadProgress progress) =>
            {
                switch (progress.Status)
                {
                    case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                            break;
                        }
                    case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                            SaveStream(stream1, FilePath);
                            break;
                        }
                    case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                            break;
                        }
                }
            };
            request.Download(stream1);
            return FilePath;
        }
    }
}
```

**What I have done so far:**

1) I went through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40946685/how-to-use-ihostingenvironment) as basic explanation but that didn't resolve the issue I have.

2) [This post](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/302/server-mappath-equivalent-in-asp-net-core) too was somehow useful as basic approach. Useful but still can't figure out what I am missing.

3) I dug more into the problem and arrived [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342064/using-ihostingenvironment-in-netcore-library) but still no luck.

Thank you very much for pointing to the right direction.

Comment: Here are some helpfuls.         https://andrewlock.net/ihostingenvironment-vs-ihost-environment-obsolete-types-in-net-core-3/

Comment: You *don't* need `System.Web` or `IHostingEnvironment`  to use Google Drive. What are you trying to do? PS: Edit your question and make *clear* what the problem is. Right now those `Error here` comments are completely hidden -3 pages down and too far to the right

Comment: Your *real* question is how to resolve local file paths, not how to use `System.Web` or `IHostingEnvironment`.

Comment: https://bytenota.com/asp-net-core-getting-project-root-directory-path/      and      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Is there a static file you're trying to "get" in your code..hosted on YOUR site?  Is that the issue?

Comment: All, thanks for reading the question. Yes, basically I am trying to resolve a local path. I have a Google Drive folder and I am trying download/upload files on it. Final goal (now only on localhost), would be that the user is able to upload/download files from google drive via `HTML` button on a user interface

Comment: @Emanuele you need to use `IHostingEnvironment.WebPath` for this in ASP.NET Core 2.x, IWebHostEnvironment.WebPath in ASP.NET Core 3.x. YOu need to *pass* that interface to your class, eg as a dependency in the constructor. The DI already knows about those interfaces. That's how controllers get them

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need `System.Web` or HttpContext. You can read the web app's root path from [IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment.webrootpath?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IHostingEnvironment_WebRootPath) in ASP.NET Core 2.x, or [IWebHostEnvironment.WebPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment.webrootpath?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IWebHostEnvironment_WebRootPath) in ASP.NET Core 3.x.

The dependency injection mechanism knows about that interface which means you can add it as a dependency to your controllers or services, eg  :

```
public class MyController : Controller 
{
    private IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public MyController(IWebHostEnvironment environment) {
        _hostingEnvironment = environment;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() {

        var path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "GoogleDriveFiles");
        ...
    }
```

You can pass the root path to your class's constructor. After all, a class named `GoogleDriveFilesRepository` only cares about its local folder, not whether it's hosted on a web or console application. For that to work, the methods should *not* be static:

```
public class GoogleDriveFilesRepository 
{

    public GoogleDriveFilesRepository (string rootPath)
    {
        _rootPath=rootPath;
    }

    public DriveService GetService()
    {
         //Operations.... 

    public List<GoogleDriveFiles> GetDriveFiles()
    {
        // Other operations....
    }

}
```

You can register that class as a service in Startup.cs :

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _env = env;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddSignleton<GoogleDriveFilesRepository>(_ =>{
            var gdriveRoot=Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath,"GoogleDriveFiles");
            return new GoogleDriveFilesRepository(gdrivePath);
        });
        ...
    }
}
```

This class can now be used as a dependency on a controller. It's no longer necessary to use `IWebHostEnvironment` in the controller :

```
public class MyController : Controller 
{
    private GoogleDriveFilesRepository _gdrive;

    public MyController(GoogleDriveFilesRepository gdrive) {
        _gdrive=gdrive;
    }
}
```

The nice thing with dependency injection is that if done right, the classes themselves don't need to know that DI is used. `MyContainer` and `GoogleDriveFilesRepository` can be used in eg a unit test without having to setup DI :

```
[Fact]
public void Just_A_Test()
{
    var repository=new GoogleDriveFilesRepository("sometestpath");
    var myController=new MyController(repository);
    myController.DoTheUpload(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is......... "I'm trying to get a static file on MY hosted web site"...then you'll want to look at this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1

The key is this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

    //OR

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "MyStaticFiles")),
        RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
    });
}
```

The default is 'wwwroot', of you can overload it with a custom value.