# ASP.NET Core 3.1 static files cannot be accessed

Tags: asp.net-core, static

I have some JSON data-configuration files that I wish to have them online as static files and read them upon my web-service initialization. So, I wish to access them internally from my code, not to make them public to external access.

Following the instructions (below) I placed them inside a **/wwwroot/Static** folder and used **app.UseStaticFiles();** in Startup.Configure(), then I try to read them via both HTML and C# code using the "**~**/Static/*.json" notation **but it does not work from C# code**.

- instructions reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1

When **locally**, I am getting error: *DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '...\Repos\VS2019\my-project-folder\**~**\**Static**\**filename.json**'.*

So, the ~ symbol is not translated to wwwroot folder name.

When **online** (as Azure App Service) I am getting: *HTTP ERROR 500*

**What** I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HostingEnvironment to get physical location:

```
public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        string data= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath.ToString()+ @"\Static\test.json");
    }
```

if Application is web Api then use ContentRoot  instead of WebRootPath.

Comment: Thank you learner! I also found a more verbally detailed solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455519/how-do-i-resolve-a-local-file-path-in-asp-net-core-3